# c# scrollbar modify LargeChange onScroll not Value

Tags: c#, scrollbar

Is there anyway to keep a scroll bar to stay at its current location (`myScrollBar.Value`) while `Scroll` event is firing during scroll box dragging?  I can get it to work after I release the scroll box after dragging it, but I am trying to make it happen **while** I am scrolling it.

```
// this example doesn't work, but it is what I am trying to do
private void myScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   // as I scroll keep resetting NewValue back to 0 -
   // this makes the value 0 only after I release the scroll box
   e.NewValue = 0;
}
```

Any suggestion on a way to go about this would be great. Thanks.